# Make {force:true} in click() function the default behavior

Tags: function, click, cypress

I am using Cypress to test a web application. I am keep getting this visibility error (**This element ''is not visible because its parent...**) when trying to click links/buttons using the *click()* function.

Cypress' suggestion to **'Fix this problem, or use *{force: true}* to disable error checking'** does help.

Now, I've been googling about how to make *{force:true}* the default behavior for the **click()** function so I do not have to write it in every use of the **click()** function but couldn't find anything so far - **click({force:true})**.

It that even possible?
Any thoughts out there?

BR

Answer (score 7):

You could write a custom command for click called forceClick.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('forceClick', {prevSubject: 'element'}, (subject, options) => {
  cy.wrap(subject).click({force: true})
});
```

Then you can use:

```
cy.forceClick()
```

Rather than

```
cy.click()
```

Answer (score 4):

You really should `scrollIntoView()` before you `.click()` in this case. I had a nasty UI bug where a button's request was being made 2x only in Cypress because we were force clicking a button not in view.

I'd suggest:

```
cy.get('button').scrollIntoView().click();
```

Comment: This is done by default when you call `.click()` : https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/interacting-with-elements#Scrolling